# Python isDisjoint() runtime

Tags: python, set, runtime

What is the algorithmic runtime of Python 2.7's `isDisjoint(other)` method for sets? Is it faster than simply doing `intersection(other)` and then checking `len()>0` of that returned intersection?

Comment: They are the same `O()` but the practicality is that there is overhead for calling functions, so if all you need is the `bool` result then use `isdisjoint()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexity in both cases is going to be `O(min(len(s), len(t))`. The only difference is that `intersection` creates a new set of all matched items and `isdisjoint` simply returns a boolean and can short-circuit as soon as a match is found.

Example that short-circuits right away:

```
>>> s1 = set(range(10**6))
>>> s2 = set([0] + list(range((10**6), 2 * (10**6))))
>>> s1.intersection(s2)
set([0])
>>> %timeit s1.isdisjoint(s2)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 94.5 ns per loop
>>> %timeit s1.intersection(s2)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.82 ms per loop
```

In this case the timings are close to each other, suggesting the matched item was found pretty late during the loop.

```
>>> s1 = set(range(10**6))
>>> s2 = set(range((10**6) - 1, 2 * (10**6)))
>>> s1.intersection(s2)
set([999999])
>>> %timeit s1.isdisjoint(s2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.37 ms per loop
>>> %timeit s1.intersection(s2)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.62 ms per loop
```