# Establish if a list of sets share data or not

Tags: python, set

Given a list of sets, how would you test if all the sets share no data:

For example:

```
[set((1,2)),set((3,)),set((4,)),set((5,))] would be True
```

but

```
[set((1,2)),set((2,)),set((4,)),set((5,))] would be False
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to sum the sizes of the sets and compare it with the size of the union:

```
def no_common_elements(sets):
    return sum(len(s) for s in sets) == len(set.union(*sets))

print(no_common_elements([set((1, 2)), set((3,)), set((4,)), set((5,))]))
# True
print(no_common_elements([set((1, 2)), set((2,)), set((4,)), set((5,))]))
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

L1 = [set((1,2)),set((3,)),set((4,)),set((5,))]
L2 = [set((1,2)),set((2,)),set((4,)),set((5,))]

def test_all_disjoint(L):
    return all(x.isdisjoint(y) for x, y in combinations(L, 2))

test_all_disjoint(L1)  # True
test_all_disjoint(L2)  # False
```

You may see [performance benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45112928/9209546) using `set.isdisjoint` over `set.union` / `set.intersection`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option which uses `numpy` and `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def shares_no_data(list_of_sets):
    # convert the list of sets into a 1d numpy array
    array = np.hstack(list(map(list, list_of_sets)))

    # no data will be shared if we have the same number of unique values 
    # as the number of items in the array
    return len(pd.unique(array)) == len(array)
```

We can test with the following:

```
l1 = [set((1,2)),set((3,)),set((4,)),set((5,))]
l2 = [set((1,2)),set((2,)),set((4,)),set((5,))]

shares_no_data(l1)
# returns True

shares_no_data(l2)
# returns False
```