# Any way to make removing value from JSON quicker?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file in which I am attempting to remove values in a separate list from this JSON file.

The list is as follows, and is approximately 10,000 values long:

```
remove_list=["apple","orange","banana"...]
```

The current code I have to remove these values from the JSON is:

```
for item in remove_list:
    for i in range(len(JSON_file)):
        for j in range(len(JSON_file[i]['query']['items'])):

            if item in JSON_file[i]['query']['items'][j]['match']:
                del JSON_file[i]['query']['items'][j]['match']
                    
            else:
                pass
```

Is there a way to make this process more efficient? It currently takes about 100 minutes to do this.

Comment: How many items are there  in `JSON_file` and how many in `data_json[i]['query']['items'][j]['match']`? How many are you removing on average? What's `data_json` vs `JSON_file` did you mean for those to be the same?

Comment: Yes I did mean for those to be the same, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can speed it up significantly by using a set instead of a list for the blacklist.

```
remove_set = set(remove_list)
for foo in JSON_file:
   for item in foo['query']['items']:
      if not remove_set.isdisjoint(item['match']):
          del item['match']
```

According to this answer, [set.isdisjoint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) should be the faster way to check if any of the blacklisted words can be found in the "match" list. (assuming it's a list)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113088/1977847

If "match" is a string, you can split it into a list of words.

```
import re
remove_set.isdisjoint(re.split(r'\W+', item['match']))
```